# how to install ssl on windows IIS server 2008

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I am trying to enable https on windows server 2008. I followed below link.

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-windows-server-2008-iis-7.0.html

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

A ssl certificate get added but at the time of binding with https, it doesn't show any certificate added. please give me some reference link or tell me if i am doing any wrong config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/06/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-77-588-510-0-after-installing-it-why/

Just make sure you create a PFX file as IIS wishes. Then you can import it easily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have the certificate from CA with .crt extension. Now i am trying to add this certificate to server and try to bind it with Default-website. And also there is no private key in the certificate. i have taken back up of private key in local.  Is there any need to convert it into .pfx file? Please reply.

Comment: @sanketThakare how did you generate the certificate request?

Comment: @ Lex Li  I followed this link:                                                                                     https://docs.druva.com/KnowledgeBase/Articles/How_To/Using_Microsoft_IIS_to_generate_CSR_and_Private_Key                       and and i get certificate from below link.                http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/2409                                                                                        Please tell me the format for IIS certificate. I have certificate with .crt extension.

Comment: @sanketThakare if you use IIS Manager to generate the certificate request, then you simply: 1) convert the .crt to a .cer file, https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/361/17/how-do-i-convert-crt-file-into-the-microsoft-cer-format 2) use the same IIS Manager on the same machine to complete the request with the .cer file. There is no need to use any other tools. 3) if you need to move this certificate to other machines, use IIS Manager to export it as a .pfx file.

Comment: @ Lex Li  ok, now as per your suggestion i follow  link:  https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Kncer-format                                                                                                  and got cer file of certificate. I successfully converted .crt to .cer file. certificate is added but at the time of binding, it disappears from drop down list. i dont understand why certificate doesn't show at the time of binding https? and when i return to my server certificate, added certificate disappears. please give any suggestion.

Comment: @sanketThakare did you use the .cer to finish the certificate request? And you must finish the request on the machine that you created the original request. Of course, to be safe you can now follow the blog post in the answer to merge the private key with the .cer file into a .pfx file.

Comment: Finally i got success with  install ssl  on windows server 2008. The issue was certificate created on different server and i was trying to install it on other server. I followed the bellow link and got success.    https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/678/0/exporting-and-restoring-a-pfx-file-to-iis. hope it will be helpful to someone.  Thanks Lex Li.